# Use jQuery to select a specific element with arbitrary data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new to jQuery and I am trying to figure out how I can select a particular element with class `organizer_listing_checkbox_container` and whose parent `.organizer_listing` has arbitrary data `data-listing_id=1234`. There are many elements with class `organizer_listing_checkbox_container` but the `data-listing_id` is unique.

I want to select that particular element and do a `.addClass()`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="organizer_listings_container">
     <div class="organizer_listing" data-listing_id=1234>

        <div class="organizer_listing_checkbox_container_container unselectable">
            <div class="organizer_listing_checkbox_container">
                <input type="checkbox" class="organizer_listing_checkbox" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[data-listing_id=90827]').addClass('foo')
```

More info about selectors:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Hi David, thanks, and I edited the question because I wrote it incorrectly. The element that I want to select does not have the arbitrary data, but its parent does.

Comment: You could add `.children('.organizer_listing_checkbox_container')` to David's selector to find the right child (should probably double up on the children with your markup), or a number of other methods once you have the right `data-listing`. You could also do some if else stuff and search upwards from `.organizer_listing_checkbox_container` and see if it matches the `data-listing` you are looking for.

Comment: Great.. i used a `.find()` because its not an immediate child. thanks!